# i am trying to store some data into a text file, there are no errors but it writes ".!toplevel.!entrywrite" instead of user input

Tags: python, tkinter

i am making a sign up page and im trying to store the email the user entered to a text file but it doesnt seem to work it stores ".!toplevel.!entrywrite" instead of user input. i am new to this python and tkinter so i dont really know what to do, the code is a little bit long sorry about that.
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

```
  from tkinter import*
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()
root.geometry('670x466')




class Goode_brothers:


    def __init__(self, parent):

        myFrame = Frame(parent)
        myFrame.pack()


        self.load = Image.open('new-dip-project\\food.jpg')
        self.render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.load)
        self.img = Label(parent, image = self.render)
        self.img.place(x = -26, y =0)
        self.img_login = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\button (3).png')
        self.b1 = Button(parent,image = self.img_login,bd = 0, bg = '#3b353b', activebackground = '#3b353b')
        self.b1.place(x = 275, y = 310)



        self.img_register = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\register.png')
        self.b2 = Button(parent,image = self.img_register, command = self.openNewWindow, bd = 0, bg = '#3b353b', activebackground = '#3b353b')
        self.b2.place(x = 265, y = 400)

        self.canvas = Canvas(parent, width = 400, height = 120)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.img4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('new-dip-project\\goode.png'))
        self.canvas.create_image(20, 20, anchor=NW, image=self.img4)



        self.email = Entry(parent).place(x = 340, y = 180)
        self.password = Entry(parent).place(x = 340, y = 250)

        self.img_label = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\label-image.png')
        self.name = Label(parent, image = self.img_label, text = "Email:", bg = '#3c3a3b').place(x = 197,y = 178)

        self.img_label_pass = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\label_pass.png')
        self.name = Label(parent, image = self.img_label_pass, text = "Password:", bg = '#3c3a3b').place(x = 177,y = 245)




    def create_pass(self):

        self.password_length = Label(self.root2, text = '')
        self.password_length.place(x = 80, y = 140)

        self.pass_word = str(self.password2.get()) #this code is getting the users input from the password entry box

        if len(self.pass_word) >= 8: #if the characters gotten from the pasword entry is less than 8, an erorr message will appear
            self.registered = Label(self.root2, text = 'You have successfully registered, this window will now automatically close', font=("open sans", "8"))
            self.registered.place(x = 80, y = 140)
            self.root2.after(4000, self.root2.destroy)
        else:
            self.password_length.configure(text="""Your password must be atleast eight characters long. Please try again""", font=("open sans", "8"))


    def save_info(self):

         self.email_reg = str(self.email2.get())
         print(self.email2)
         file = open('emails.txt', 'w')
         file.write(str(self.email2))




    def create_email(self):

        self.username_length = Label(self.root2, text = '', font = '40')
        self.username_length.place(x = 165, y = 140)

        self.email_reg = str(self.email2.get())

        if len(self.email_reg) >= 1: #if user has inputted a letter or number it will allow it to go to the next function
            self.save_info()
            self.create_pass()
            self.username_length.destroy()
        else:


            self.username_length.configure(text='Please enter your username or password', font=("open sans", "8"))
            self.username_length.after(3000, self.username_length.destroy)




    def openNewWindow(self):

        # Toplevel object which will
        # be treated as a new window
        self.root2 = Toplevel(root)

        # sets the title of the
        # Toplevel widget
        self.root2.title("New Window")

        # sets the geometry of toplevel
        self.root2.geometry("500x300")

        self.load2 = Image.open('new-dip-project\\registerscreen3.jpg')
        self.render2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.load2)
        self.img2 = Label(self.root2, image = self.render2)
        self.img2.place(x = -2, y =0)

        self.img_label2 = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\label-image.png')
        self.name = Label(self.root2, image = self.img_label, bg = '#292929').place(x = 130,y = 102)

        self.img_label_pass2 = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\label_pass.png')
        self.name = Label(self.root2, image = self.img_label_pass, bg = '#292929').place(x = 120,y = 173)

        self.email2 = Entry(self.root2)
        self.email2.place(x = 280, y = 104)

        self.password2 = Entry(self.root2)
        self.password2.place(x = 280, y = 180)

        self.img_register2 = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\register.png')
        self.b3 = Button(self.root2,image = self.img_register2, command = self.create_email, bd = 0, bg = '#0d0d0d', activebackground = '#0d0d0d')
        self.b3.place(x = 180, y = 250)

        self.img_reg2 = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\regtitle.png')
        self.name9 = Label(self.root2, image = self.img_reg2, bg = '#131313')
        self.name9.place(x = 109, y = 10)







if __name__ == "__main__":
    e = Goode_brothers(root)
    root.title('Goode brothers')
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `file.write(self.email_reg)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using `var = StringVar()` to set option `textvariable - var` when initialize `Entry`, and get content of `Entry` by `var.get()`.

example Code

```py
from tkinter import *

def on_click():
    print(entry_text.get())

root = Tk()

font = ("Courier New", 32)

entry_text = StringVar()
entry = Entry(root, textvariable=entry_text, font=font)
entry.place(x=0, y=0)

button = Button(root, text='Check', command=on_click, font= font)
button.place(x=0, y=64)

root.mainloop()
```

Following statement will get value `None` for `self.email`

```py
self.email = Entry(parent).place(x = 340, y = 180)
```

should be

```py
self.email = Entry(parent)
self.email.place(x = 340, y = 180)
```